# Doesn't iOS 5 include the ability to more natively select and track multiple UITableView cells?

Tags: ios5, uitableview, multipleselection

I could have sworn this was a new feature in iOS 5, but I have been looking all over the place and not finding anything. Isn't there a more native approach to selecting multiple rows now?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your instantiated tableview has the usual name of tableView:

```
[tableView setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES];
[tableView setAllowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing:YES];
```

Will allow you to select more than one row.

You can read the index paths of your selected rows thusly:

```
NSArray *paths = [tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
```

Documentation:

- [allowsMultipleSelecttion](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW51#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/allowsMultipleSelection)
- [indexPathsForSelectedRows](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW51#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/indexPathsForSelectedRows)